# Angular Images in Component Folder: Let the Compiler Move Images to Assets

Tags: angular

I want to make my components portable to other projects, therefore I want to have all the images contained in the component folder and let the compiler take care of it.

I found different solutions which I all don't quite like:

## 1) Defining different folders in the angular.json:

[Is it mandatory to keep images in assets folder in Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46149846/is-it-mandatory-to-keep-images-in-assets-folder-in-angular-2)

I don't like this approach because it requires a lot of manual work.

## 2) Defining a path variable within the component

[Angular 2 img src in a relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36287518/angular-2-img-src-in-a-relative-path)

This approach creates a lot of extra variables.

My goal would be to do s.th. like this

A) Referencing to the image like all other images:

```
<img *ngIf="images[sensor.model]" [src]="'assets/images/' + images[sensor.model]"/>
```

B) Configuring the compiler to move the images from all folders to assets, e.g. in an old AngularJs project where I used gulp, this could be done with globbing:

```
gulp.task('images', function () {
  return gulp.src([paths.src + '/**/*.{jpg,jpeg,png,svg,gif}', '!'+'/**/*/*-sprite*'])
    .pipe($.rename({dirname: ''}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dist + '/assets/images/'));
});
```

And it could be easily achieved, that images are only copied if images change for faster compiling:

```
gulp.watch(paths.src + '/**/*.{jpg,jpeg,png,svg,gif}', ['images']);
```

## Question

Can the compiler be set up to search for images and move them to `assets/images` and would there be a downside to it ( I read that assets are static for faster compiling ).